Sum of Simplex Volumes with Corners from Points in Convex Configuration
Question:
given $k,\,k>n$ points in convex configuration and general position in $n$ dimensional Euclidean space, i.e. no $n+1$ points of which are co-hyperplanar,

what can be said about how the sum of the volumes of the set of simplices defined by the subsets of $n+1$ points depends on the volume of the convex polytope defined by all $k$ points?

